# Is Real time pitch shifting possible with AudioUnit?

Tags: signal-processing, audio-streaming, pitch, trigonometry

I am playing two sine wave tone generated on the fly with the help of AudioUnit. I need to give the user a UISlider which helps him to change the pitch of the tone on the fly. I am stuck in setting pitch for the tone with AudioUnits, please provide some code snippet to change the pitch with help of AudioUnits.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the pitch of a generated waveform, such as a sine wave, being copied into an AudioUnit callback buffer, is certainly possible.  Exactly how to change it depends on how you are generating the sine wave.  If by table look up, then you can change the table step size and interpolate.  If by calling the sinf() function, you can change the delta phase change per sample in the function call to match some relationship with your slider position. etc.

However the term "real-time pitch shifting" often refers to another different and more complicated DSP process, such as a phase vocoder used for combined time-pitch modification.  Which do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for clarifications hotpaw2.I am exactly using simple sinf() function to generate tones, so as you said it should be possible for pitch shifting. Now please help me to do this, I have no clue to accomplish this. Is it possible to shift the pitch if i give pitch values like F2#,G2,G2# etc,. My tone generator is similar to this http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html

Comment: You need to look into some dsp books. This is not a simple matter that someone can just do for you.